# Knockout cancel update from jQuery UI dialog

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I have parent model `person`. The view model has an observable array of `person`. To edit/add a person i have a jQuery UI dialog (Ok/Cancel).

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.personEntry = ko.observable(new person());
    self.people = ko.observableArray();
    self.populatePeople = function(jsonPeopleObj){//adds person objects to people array};
};
```

The `personEntry` submodel is bound to the jQuery UI dialog using `with` binding. A table is produced using the `foreach` binding on the `people` observable array.

Now when I try to amend a record I call the following function on click of the row.

```
function rowSelected(item,event){
    viewModel.personEntry(item);
    openDialog();
}
```

This opens the dialog with selected row's details on the jQuery UI dialog. However if I change a value and then press the cancel on the dialog, the table still gets amended with a new value which should not happen. Any thoughts?

I can put a sample code if required.

Comment: You *absolutely* should use [knockout-jqueryui](http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/), which provides well-working knockout bindings for the various standard jQuery UI widgets. Before you do anything else, look at [the sample for the dialog widget](http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/dialog.html). Get rid of your custom click event handlers and try to get it to work this way instead. If your issue persists, add sample code to your question.

Comment: I have solve this problem by creating a new instance of the person object and assign it the values from the item. Then I am passing this new person object to the personEntry item. This fixed it

Comment: For good karma you can post your working solution and along with a small paragraph of explanation as an answer. Maybe someone else will find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with a bit of work around...

https://jsfiddle.net/ramkiFiddle/v29exev5/59/

```
self.amendDetails = function(item, event) {
    itemProgressed = item;
    operation = 'Amend';
    var tempObj = new Person(item.Name(), item.Age());
    pageModel.personEntry(tempObj);
    $("#personEntry").dialog('open');
  }
```